# Swift: how to use dispatch_once to dequeue a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, singleton

In my app I have a `UITableViewController` whose cells are very dynamic according to their content (overall images and text) and I need to calculate the height for a cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath()`. In order to get this I need to dequeue a cell by identifier. I can't simply instantiate a cell of its custom class because it would lack the constraints defined in interface builder and the calculus wouldn't be right. On the contrary, I know that calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath()` will cause an infinite recursive loop. Thus, reading some posts here and some tutorials by Ray Wenderlich, I was able to write this code in `heightForRowAtIndexPath()`

```
var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
var cell = nil
dispatch_once(&token) {
  cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BigTextCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BigTextCell
}
/*adjust cell constraints and return its height*/
```

This seems to work for everybody (at least in Objective-C) but I don't know why it does not for me. As expected, it blocks in an infinite loop. Why?
I must admit that I've never used singleton and I am unfamiliar to them but I thought this would be right.
Any idea?

**UPDATE**

I've just tried the following but it does not work:

```
  var cell:BigTextCell!
  dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
    cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BigTextCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BigTextCell
  }
  for constraint in cell.paragraph.constraints {
    if (constraint.identifier == "longTextConstraint") {
      constraint.constant = cell.paragraph.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: cell.paragraph.frame.width, height: CGFloat.max)).height
      return constraint.constant
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

declare `var onceToken = dispatch_once_t()` outside the method.

put it as a property of your ViewController

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var onceToken = dispatch_once_t()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            //your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm afraid it doesn't work. I've just updated my question which the code I wrote following your suggestions, with `onceToken` as property of the class...maybe I'm missing something

Comment: maybe you should claim a global cell. because you need the same origin cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath()` . global cell would work

Comment: sorry, what do you mean for global cell? maybe the fact I should dequeue it at the beginning in viewDidLoad?

Comment: It's exactly what I tried yeasteday, giving to the dequeue function a new instance of index path for section 0 (the unique section) and row 1 but I get an exception for a wrong index path...maybe it doesn't work like that...

Comment: You don't have to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in the viewDidLoad. Instead you init the global cell using the original method. like [[UITableViewCell alloc] init]

Comment: I can't do it...I have altrady tried it and as I said, if I instantiate a cell using only its custom class then there won't be the constraints defined in the interface builder and the calculus of the heigth would be wrong

Comment: the interface builder get wrong size during viewDidLoad. It'll be correct in viewWillAppear. perhaps try to init in viewWillAppear